# How to find TMainMenu parent of TMenuItem?

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, tmenuitem

I have a standard `TMainMenu` which contains some `TMenuItem` elements. How can I find dynamically a parent main menu object from one of them?

The following code brings a compiler error already in the first executable line:

```
procedure TMenuItemHelper.AlignToRight;
const
  P3 = False;
var
  info: TMenuItemInfo;
  buffer: array[0..78] of WideChar;
  mainMenu: TMainMenu;
begin
  if Self.Parent is TMainMenu then
    mainMenu := (Self.Parent as TMainMenu)
  else
    raise EMenuItemHelper.Create(strExcMenuItemNotFirstLevel);

  info.cbSize := SizeOf(info);
  info.fMask := MIIM_TYPE;
  info.dwTypeData := buffer;
  info.cch := SizeOf(buffer);
  GetMenuItemInfo(mainMenu.Handle, Self.Command, P3, info);

  info.fType := info.fType or MFT_RIGHTJUSTIFY;
  SetMenuItemInfo(mainMenu.Handle, Self.Command, P3, info);
end;
```

The error message is following:

```
[dcc32 Error] E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMenuItem' and 'TMainMenu'
```

I can not see any related question, but the solution is probably quite simple.

Comment: Get it from `GetParentMenu`.

Comment: Thank you, @Victoria! It works!

Comment: You're welcome! Just, one detail. Your exception `strExcMenuItemNotFirstLevel` sounds like some text which could say that the item is not a top level item (that is a subitem). Note, that `GetParentMenu` iterates to the top level item and takes the menu object reference from that one.

Comment: That's very true, I have already changed. Thank you for your support, @Victoria!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from [Victoria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8041231/victoria):

```
  if Self.GetParentMenu is TMainMenu then
    mainMenu := (Self.GetParentMenu as TMainMenu)
  else
    raise EMenuItemHelper.Create(strExcMenuItemParentIsNotAMainMenu);
```